# Where to find the broken key parts?

Tags: deltarune

In Deltarune, I've found a singular part of a broken key. It's called 'Broken Key B.' I know you have to take it to the Blacksmith for him to fix it, and I *maybe* know what it unlocks. I've searched all in the maze, the forest, and the fields. I'm currently at the elevator in the Card Castle. So, I haven't searched past there yet.

Answer (score 5):

There are three parts to the broken key:

- Part A is given to you by Seam if you go to his seap and ask about

> Jevil. You need to have encountered the secret door in the prison first.

- Part B is found at the end of a secret path in the forest, south of the dancers. The path is revealed by the background mist.
- Part C is behind a a puzzle at the end of the field. You need to enter the order of the floors of the card castle

If all three parts are taken to Malius, he will fix the key.